# how to transfer a large amount of data through spring rest api

Tags: rest, spring-boot, download, large-files

I want to send the huge amount of data through spring rest api. some people have suggested like to make into the chunks and then send via rest. can anyone suggest me how to make into possible.

Comment: you can zip data

Comment: actually the problem is i am getting the 2GB tar file.When i am sending the tar file through rest api it is taking huge time. Then some people has suggested me like to make into a chunks of each 100 mb and then sent.  i am able to make into smaller chunks but i am unable to sent via rest.

Comment: that would be good, i think is the best way to do , you are sending the data in bytes???

Comment: yes after making small chunks of that particular tar file and placed in a (test) directory. Then after that  i am hitting this url  (http://localhost:8080/rest/download/home/user/test/)  where (http://localhost:8080/rest/download/) is a rest url and  (home/user/test/ ) is my directory  and whatever chunks  are there in the test directory, i have to make it into download. But only one chunk i can be able to download although i have written the code to download all chunks. Later i got to know that  through rest you can able to download only one file.how to do download all the files in directory?

Comment: you can add a header to package info in the download api response, that indicate wat is the total of the calls to need to do, and you can have a control of the dowload package, example if you cant dowload third package (any reason), you can recall that

Comment: It means you are asking me to do like how many chunks are there in the directory ,that many rest calls i have to do to . did  i understand correctly?

Comment: yes, im bad to explain but is good you got it